# How to assign a value to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I get this error :

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘char *’
```

When I try to compile this:

```c
struct libro {
    char titolo[100];
    char autore[50];
    int anno_pubblicazione;
    float prezzo;
};
typedef struct libro Libri;

int main (void) {
    Libri scaffale[150];

    scaffale[1].titolo = "last of mohicans";
    printf("\n%s\n",scaffale[1].titolo);

    return 0;
}
```

I wonder how to assign a value to a specific field on a specified member of the array.

Comment: you need to use `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C99 You can use designated initializers:

```
Libri scaffale[150] = { [1] = {"last of mohicans"} };
```

The problem with your code is that arrays are not assignable. Arrays can be *initialized* and initialization uses syntax that looks similar to assignment, but it is not the same thing.

If you do need assignment, then what you have to do in C is write a loop that assigns individual elements of the array. Or use a pre-existing function that does this, if the array type is such that there's such a function available. For a null terminated char array there is such a function, called [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).

---

Although C++ inherits all of C's problems with raw arrays for compatibility, in C++ you can use `std::array` to get arrays with more reasonable behavior: they're copiable, assignable, using pass-by-value syntax actually does that instead of inserting some bizarre conversion to a pointer to the first element of the array, etc. And the C++ `std::array` type has zero overhead compared to raw arrays: `std::array` will result in identical object layout and code generation as raw arrays. The availability of a reasonable array type is one good reason to use C++ over C.

Of course in this case it's likely that in C++ you would have `titolo` and `autore` be `string`s instead  arrays, in which case there would be performance differences since the representation would not be identical to raw arrays. Whether the performance would be better or worse depends on the exact program data. The performance could be better due to a more compact representation (the small string optimization), or it could be slower if the string data is too large for that and there end up being a lot of memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how you can set an element of an array during its declaration and assign an element after the declaration of the array using function `strcpy`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct libro 
{
    char titolo[100];
    char autore[50];
    int anno_pubblicazione;
    float prezzo;
} ;

typedef struct libro Libri;



int main(void) 
{
    Libri scaffale[150] = { [1].titolo = "last of mohicans" };

    puts( scaffale[1].titolo );

    strcpy( scaffale[0].titolo, "first of mohicans" );  

    puts( scaffale[0].titolo );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
last of mohicans
first of mohicans
```

Take into account that arrays do not have the assignment operator. You have to copy elements of arrays. For example for character arrays that contain strings you can use standard function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to arrays in c, trye changing this

```
scaffale[1].titolo = "last of mohicans";
```

to

```
strcpy(scaffale[1].titolo, "last of mohicans");
```

you need to copy the literal to the array.

Also, the first element of an array in c, has index `0` not `1` so to popuplate the first element of the array you need

```
strcpy(scaffale[0].titolo, "last of mohicans");
```

**note**: the `strcpy` fucntion is declared in the "strings.h" header, as well as other string handling functions.